# SEStandard - A .NET Standard 1.1 compliant Stack Exchange client library that supports API v2.2

Tags: library, api-v2.2, c#, .net

> Please note that SEStandard is still under development. It is currently at version `1.0.0-rc`, and is a release candidate. While you can expect the API not to change, you *might* come across bugs. Please report them [here](https://github.com/RavinduL/SEStandard/issues).
>
> This post will be updated in synchrony with the code.

[image]

### About

SEStandard is a C# library for querying the Stack Exchange API that,

- Supports [all endpoints](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs?tab=category#docs) of the Stack Exchange API version `2.2`.
- [.NET Standard `1.1`](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.1.md) compliant.
- Task based, and `async`hronous.
- Provides helper methods for [implicit authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

### Code Snippet

To list the top 10 highest voted questions on Stack Overflow,

```
using RavinduL.SEStandard;
using Scopes = RavinduL.SEStandard.Models.Scopes;
using QuestionSort = RavinduL.SEStandard.Models.QuestionSort;

var client = new StackExchangeClient();

var query = await client.Questions.GetAsync
(
    site: "stackoverflow",
    pagesize: 10,
    order: Order.Descending,
    sort: QuestionSort.Votes
);

foreach (var question in query.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{question.Title} (score: {question.Score})");
}
```

Please refer to the [README](https://github.com/RavinduL/SEStandard) on GitHub for information on how to use this library.

### Installation

To install this library via **NuGet** ([package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RavinduL.SEStandard)),

```
    PM> Install-Package RavinduL.SEStandard -Version 1.0.0-rc
```

To install the NuGet package via the **.NET Core CLI**,

```
    PS> dotnet add package RavinduL.SEStandard --version 1.0.0-rc
```

### Platform

SEStandard is a [.NET Standard 1.1](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.1.md) compliant library and is therefore supported by all implementations version 1.1 and greater, of the .NET Standard (i.e. .NET Core, .NET Framework, and Mono applications, Xamarin, Universal Windows Platform, Windows Phone, etc.)

Please visit https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support for a list of platforms that this library can be used on.

### Code

The source code of SEStandard is hosted on GitHub at https://github.com/RavinduL/SEStandard

Please refer to the [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/RavinduL/SEStandard/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) document for information on how to build the library, repository layout, etc.

### License

SEStandard is licensed under the [MIT License](https://github.com/RavinduL/SEStandard/blob/master/LICENSE).